# Django using include() as path() argument

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm learning Django.

In the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) it says:

> The **path()** function is passed four arguments, two required: **route** and **view**, and two optional: kwargs, and name. At this point, it’s worth reviewing what these arguments are for.
>
> **path() argument: view**
>
> When Django finds a matching pattern, it calls the specified view function with an HttpRequest object as the first argument and any “captured” values from the route as keyword arguments. We’ll give an example of this in a bit.

In my opinion, the `view` is a function that takes a `HttpRequest` as argument and returns a `HttpResponse`.

but in `mysite/urls.py` the `path()` is used like this `path("polls/", include("polls.urls"))`,
and the `inclue` method returns a tuple `(urlconf_module, app_name, namespace)`, not a function.

Why can `include()` be used here?

I'll appreciate it if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/) says that

> The view argument is a view function or the result of as_view() for class-based views. It can also be an django.urls.include().

And if you look at the source code,

```
def _path(route, view, kwargs=None, name=None, Pattern=None):
    if isinstance(view, (list, tuple)):
        # For include(...) processing.
        pattern = Pattern(route, is_endpoint=False)
        urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
        return URLResolver(
            pattern,
            urlconf_module,
            kwargs,
            app_name=app_name,
            namespace=namespace,
        )
    elif callable(view):
        pattern = Pattern(route, name=name, is_endpoint=True)
        return URLPattern(pattern, view, kwargs, name)
    else:
        raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
```

you'll see it simply checks the arguments type and do different things depending on if it's a tuple or a callable.